# FANN: How do I find a balance between the desired error and the bit fail?

Tags: neural-network

I want the network to stop training when the bit fail is 0.
When that normally happens, the desired error is pretty low. But If I set the desired error too low, the network will keep training.. even over training even if the bit fail is 0....

How to I find a good balance between desired error and bit fail?

TL;DR: How do I calculate the lowest possible desired error such that the network stops training when the bit fail reaches 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method of type [fann_callback_type](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_data-h.html#fann_callback_type), let's call it *trainCallback* and then set this method as a callback to your NN (using the [fann_set_callback](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_train-h.html#fann_set_callback) method)

This method - *trainingCallback* -  will be called while training, instead of printing out details of the training.
In this callback you have access to all the information you need (MSE, bitfail etc. - check out the signature at the links above) and if you return a value smaller than 0, than the training will stop.

Hope it helps

```
int trainCallback(struct fann *ann, struct fann_train_data *train, 
                           unsigned intmax_epochs, unsigned int epochs_between_reports,
                           float desired_error, unsigned int epochs) {
   if(/*your condition*/)
       return -1;
   return 0;
}

/* in your code */
{
...
fann_set_callback(ptrToFANN, &trainCallback);
...
}
```

Comment: in libfann you should be able to stop computing when bit fail is 0 by setting desired_error to 0 as parameter for train_ondata or train_on_file and using the set_train_stop_function(libfann.STOPFUNC_BIT). but it doesn"t work at least through the python binding. So this answer is your best bet

Comment: What Matyas describe is a differential stopping criterion, which you can implement easily in any neural network implementation. All you have to do is to keep in memory the previous NN links weights, and compute the absolute difference of the change for each link at the next learning iteration: if the sum of all those difference (thus you compute the euclidian distance) is smaller than the threshold you gave, or even 0, then you can quit.